# How copyscape uses google API

Tags: php, google-api, google-search

How copyscape uses google API?
The ajax api works only on browsers with javascript enabled, So this api is not used. The SOAP api is not used, because it is not allowed to be used for commercial use and no more than 100 queries are allowed per day.

Answer (score 2):

Copyscape not uses Google api instead it uses Google search it does a simple curl request to http://www.google.com/search?q=Search Keywords here . Then uses regexp patterns to find title, descriptions and links and shows to user. But this strictly violates Google terms of service which can also get them ban, so they uses proxies(or any other ip hiding method) to hide their ip for each search

Comment: I hardly doubt that's all they do. @RGAT's answer is much more detailed and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

From their FAQ they have explained how they do it.

---

> **Where does Copyscape get its results?**
>
> Copyscape uses Google and Yahoo! as search providers, under agreed
>   terms. These search providers send standard search results to
>   Copyscape, without any post-processing. Copyscape uses complex
>   proprietary algorithms to modify these search results in order to
>   provide a ?plagiarism checking service. Any charges are for
>   Copyscape's value-added services, not for the provision of search
>   results by the search providers.
>
> http://www.copyscape.com/faqs.php#providers

---

**Analysis**

CopyScape made us 100% sure that Google and Yahoo have special agreements. I am 80% sure that CopyScape are using a similar search solution (probably undisclosed but similar) to [Google Enterprise Search](http://www.google.com.ph/enterprise/search/) provided by the search engines.

CopyScape does not do scraped results, but is fetching API based formats like json and xml. Which is good for the providers (Google and Yahoo) for bandwidth and response time improvements. I came up with this part due to my previous attempts to scrape google search results via python by phrase searches ("phrase matching"). Your scraping bot cannot and no known way to bypass 503 that google will respond after couple of hundred results (100 search intervals or 50 search intervals).

They obviously did not do some browser automation then fetching data between web drivers and programming languages like python. I have tried doing it and it gave similar results except that the automated searcher will need some manual intervention for the captcha which will then let you continue with the scraping. I also tried using some latest bypass which was patch in just minutes/seconds. Surely they did not do any automated scraping from search engines and if ever they are doing it. It will not work long term.

**How they are using their special privilege?**

Since they have paid off / have special terms they can now automate from the special APIs. They are either using Google Search Enterprise & Yahoo Search Marketing Enterprise or they have something more special solution.

**Not Using List**

- Regular / Free APIs (Not sure if google and yahoo made it free for them)
- Scrapers (Scrapy, Beautiful Soup, Selenium and Etc)

**Using List**

- Enterprise Level API
- Server Bash Scripts / Python Scripts / Ruby Scripts / PHP Scripts for scalabilities and such.

**Hoping**

I hope someone from CopyScape can leak information so that people won't be guessing and CopyScape should have more competition since there are only some plagarism checkers out there which are highly reliable and regarded (probably 1-10 only).